# how to insert multiple records in php

Tags: php, database

I have a problem while inserting multiple record in to the db

HTML

```
<input type="input" name="row[][name]"> 
<input type="input" name="row[][surname]">
<input type="input" name="row[][name]"> 
<input type="input" name="row[][surname]">
```

PHP

```
$returnedData = $_POST['row'];
$sql = array(); 
foreach( $returnedData as $row ) {
    $sql[] = '("'.mysql_real_escape_string($row['name']).'", '.mysql_real_escape_string($row['surname']).')';
}
mysql_query('INSERT INTO tableName (name, surname) VALUES '.implode(',', $sql));
```

But the error is It opens 4 rows while I mean it opens a new row for each input.

How can I insert two records ?

NEW INFO

when I write posted values by usingforeach I can see the values properly, the thing is I couldnt find the solution to insert in to my table

`foreach($returnedData as $data) {
        echo '<pre>';
       echo  $data['name'];
       echo  $data['surName'];
  }`

Comment: First take a look into `$returnedData`, then decide how to iterate over it. And if you do the same with `$sql` instead of directly running the query, you can faster find out.

Comment: the problem is not that you can foreach and array or not, but *how* you foreach it. So the problem is not inserting here, it's before the inserting.

Comment: I've left you an answer giving you a better look onto the variables and made you an online example that shows a bit better how it works.

Comment: just my opinion, i would be tempted to use names of 'name[]' and 'surname[]' rather than the multi-dimensional arrays that you are creating. To see them just do: var_dump($_POST). If you do want to keep them together in one entry then i think 'row[name][]' will be easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

to insert a row for each instance of your post it should be:

```
foreach( $returnedData as $row ) {
    $sql[] = '("'.mysql_real_escape_string($row['name']).'", '.mysql_real_escape_string($row['surname']).')';
mysql_query('INSERT INTO tableName (name, surname) VALUES '.implode(',', $sql));
}
```

cause your way only inserts the last one.

I think that is what your trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

For the HTML form as you outline it in your question, the `$_POST['row']` contains the form-data in the following structure:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Lara
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [surname] => Larasen
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Linda
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [surname] => Lindasen
        )

)
```

As you've shown in your `foreach` iteration, you pick each entry *and* you have error displaying disabled. So you don't get the message that most often the data you're looking for is missing *and* your iterating 4 times instead of two.

Most likely you wanted to create the following HTML form:

```
<input type="input" name="row[0][name]"> 
<input type="input" name="row[0][surname]">

<input type="input" name="row[1][name]"> 
<input type="input" name="row[1][surname]">
```

Which gives you the `$_POST['row']` the form-data in this following, but different structure that should be easier for you to iterate:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Lara
            [surname] => Larasen
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Linda
            [surname] => Lindasen
        )

)
```

Bottom line is: PHP needs a little help from you with the outer array-index so that name and surname are properly grouped.

You can try out both forms your own with this demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/kxUsru

---

In case codepad viper looses the code, here is the source of the example:

```
<form method="post">
<input type="input" name="row[][name]"> 
<input type="input" name="row[][surname]">

<input type="input" name="row[][name]"> 
<input type="input" name="row[][surname]">

<input type="submit">
</form>


<form method="post">
<input type="input" name="row[0][name]"> 
<input type="input" name="row[0][surname]">

<input type="input" name="row[1][name]"> 
<input type="input" name="row[1][surname]">

<input type="submit">
</form>

<pre>
<?php
    echo htmlspecialchars(print_r($_POST['row'], TRUE));
?>
</pre>
```